# Is it okay to have no A records for a domain?

Tags: dns

There is one domain I'm using for email only. MX records are set up and everything works. The A records for `@` and `www` are pointing to a machine, which just redirects to `google.com`.

I am now wondering if I could just delete the A records for `@` and `www`. Are there any consequences except that the domain wouldn't be available via a browser if I do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is not a violation of any rule to not have an A record for a domain (none of my domains have an A RR).

Answer (score 5):

You should be covered by your mx records and cname.

Mail Exchange records direct email to servers for a domain, and are listed in order of priority. If mail can't be delivered using the first priority record, the second priority record is used, and so on.

"A records (also known as host records) are the central records of DNS. These records link a domain, or subdomain, to an IP address.

A records and IP addresses do not necessarily match on a one-to-one basis. Many A records correspond to a single IP address, where one machine can serve many web sites. Alternatively, a single A record may correspond to many IP addresses. This can facilitate fault tolerance and load distribution, and allows a site to move its physical location.

Google Apps does not support IP addresses alone. Instead of using A records, you can set up email and web publishing by modifying your MX and CNAME records with your domain host."

Answer (score -1):

If you have a static IP use A records.

`A` / `AAAA` record is to redirect your domain to particular IP.

If you set NS records for your share hosting then there is no need to set an `A` record in DNS manager.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question. The OP is asking whether it is OK to not have `A` records in the DNS zone when there is no website to host. Are you suggesting that `A` records are a requirement?

Comment: If u don't have host remove the 'A' record , A record is to redirect your domain to that particular value