# What should be domain name A-record for VPS server's main domain?

Tags: dns, vps, dns-servers, dns-lookup

While updating the child name servers of the main domain of my VPS server I mistakenly changed the A-records to the server's IP.
Will that have any effect of the name servers?

I found this question while researching on it:
[Is it okay to have no A records for a domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26985/is-it-okay-to-have-no-a-records-for-a-domain)
But I did't quite get it.

I have updated the name servers more than 24 hrs ago but still propagation has not yet completed (previously it got propagated within couple of hours).
The sub-domains of the main domain are not working.
Sub-domains of addon domains are working.

Even the google webmaster page is showing dns errors.
I am loosing search engine traffic drastically.
Please give a solution ASAP.

Comment: Might want to flag that URL as NSFW...

Comment: @IvovanderVeeken removed URL. The image might help.

Comment: You may need to call your host for help.

Answer (score 1):

You changed the A records of your domain instead of nameserver's hostname IP addresses. So flow would be like, your nameservers will locate DNS zone and web request will lookup for a webserver's A record to serve the website page. Since you have changed the A record, it will look at incorrect server (where website does not exist) and hence DNS error. If you have corrected everything then there's nothing you can do at your end except waiting. To lower down the propagation period, you can change the TTL time of DNS records.

Comment: What should be the A records? Where can I find the A records?

Comment: your domain's A record should be the IP address of your web server (where your website is actually hosted).